# python - add cookie to cookiejar

Tags: python, cookies

How do I create a cookie and add it to a CookieJar instance in python? 
I have all the info for the cookie (name, value, domain, path, etc) and I don't want to extract a new cookie with a http request.

I tried this but it looks like SimpleCookie class is not compatible with CookieJar (is there another Cookie class?)

```
import Cookie
c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
c["name"]="value"
c['name']['expires'] = 0
c['name']['path'] = "/"
c['name']['domain'] = "mydomain.com"
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
cj.set_cookie(cookie)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    cj.set_cookie(cookie)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/cookielib.py", line 1627, in set_cookie
    if cookie.domain not in c: c[cookie.domain] = {}
AttributeError: 'SimpleCookie' object has no attribute 'domain'
```

Comment: What is the context that you're using this ?  This stuff has been reimplemented a lot in python web serving and request frameworks.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at cookielib, you get:

```
try:
    from cookielib import Cookie, CookieJar         # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from http.cookiejar import Cookie, CookieJar    # Python 3
cj = CookieJar()
# Cookie(version, name, value, port, port_specified, domain, 
# domain_specified, domain_initial_dot, path, path_specified, 
# secure, discard, comment, comment_url, rest)
c = Cookie(None, 'asdf', None, '80', '80', 'www.foo.bar', 
       None, None, '/', None, False, False, 'TestCookie', None, None, None)
cj.set_cookie(c)
print cj
```

Gives:

```
<cookielib.CookieJar[<Cookie asdf for www.foo.bar:80/>]>
```

There are no real sanity checks for the instantiation parameters. The ports have to be strings, not int.

Comment: while True, this does not touch whether the `Cookie` module can be made compatible with the `cookielib` module, or whether not.

Comment: Probably you would just create an own `Cookie` type in that case, which offers both interfaces. Cookiejar isn't really picky about what it gets as a cookie. The new cookie just requires `domain`, `path` and `name` attributes and must not have `items`. That's it basically. `cookielib` internals are really some lightweight lecture, easy to digest and a very recommended reading.

Comment: I just noticed - Cookie() takes 15 parameters, and you supply 16 when calling it. Is this a typo?

Comment: I guess the 16th was this optional rfc2109 parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial point here is that method `cj.set_cookie` expects an object of class `cookielib.Cookie` as its parameter (so *yes, there is another Cookie class*), *not* an object of class `Cookie.SimpleCookie` (or any other class found in module `Cookie`). These classes are (as observed) simply not compatible, despite the confusing similarity of names.

Note that the parameter list of the constructor for `cookielib.Cookie` might have changed at some point in the past (and might change again in the future as this class does not seem to be expected to be used outside of `cookielib`), at least `help(cookielib.Cookie)` currently gives me

```
# Cookie(version, name, value, port, port_specified, domain,
# domain_specified, domain_initial_dot, path, path_specified,
# secure, expires, discard, comment, comment_url, rest, rfc2109=False)
```

Note the additional `expires` parameter and the parameter `rfc2109` used but not documented in the code in @Michael's answer above, so the example should become something like

```
c = Cookie(None, 'asdf', None, '80', True, 'www.foo.bar', 
   True, False, '/', True, False, '1370002304', False, 'TestCookie', None, None, False)
```

(also replacing some Boolean constants for `None` where applicable).

Comment: if these two are incompatible, which modules are using either of them respectively? eg. is `Cookie` compatible with any standard-library module? what about `cookielib`? Why should one want use one over the other?