# Use urllib2 cookie in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to scrape and interact with a site. Using BeautifulSoup, I can do MOST of what I want, but not all of it. Selenium should able to handle that portion. I can get it to working using the Selenium Firefox Plugin. I just need to automate it now. My problem is, the area that I need to interact with sits behind a login prompt, which is handled via an OpenID Provider.

Fortunately, I was able to use this bookmarklet to get the cookie that is set. `javascript:void(document.cookie=prompt(document.cookie,document.cookie));` This allows me to login an parse the page using BeautifulSoup.

This is done via this code:

```
jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders.append(("Cookie","__cfduid=<hex string>; __utma=59652655.1231969161.1367166137.1368651910.1368660971.15; __utmz=59652655.1367166137.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=<a session id>; __utmb=59652655.1.10.1368660971; __utmc=59652655"))
page = opener.open(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(scrap1)
...parse stuff...
```

At this point, the `jar` is empty and I need to do the final interaction (clicking on a couple DIV elements and verifying that another DIV has been updated appropriately. However, I need the above cookie jar to populate in a selenium session so that I am logged in appropriately.

How can I move the above cookie into something that selenium knows and recognizes?

I've tried code like this

```
for c in jar:
    driver.add_cookie({'name':c.name, 'value':c.value, 'path':'/', 'domain':c.domain})
```

But, since the `jar` is empty, this doesn't work. Is there a way to put this cookie in the jar? Since I'm bypassing the OpenId login by using this cookie, I'm not receiving anything back from the server.

Comment: Why not use Selenium and log in directly? Use `send_keys()` to write the appropriate login credentials to the appropriate elements and then send the form. Its a lot less messy.

Comment: [python - add cookie to cookiejar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4685337/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be approaching this backwards. Instead of passing a cookie to Selenium, why not perform the login with Selenium directly?

For example:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

browser.get('http://www.mywebsite.com/')
username_input = browser.find_element_by_id('username') #Using id only as an example
password_input = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
login_button = browser.find_element_by_id('login')

username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input.send_keys(password)
login_button.click()
```

This way you won't have to worry about manually collecting cookies.

From here, you can grab the page source and pass it to BeautifulSoup:

```
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
```

I hope this helped.